# How to overwrite the first array with the second one?

Tags: javascript

Here's the arrays:

```js
const firstArr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    code: '1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    code: '2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    code: '3'
  },
]

const secondArr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    code: '1',
    bool: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    code: '2',
    bool: true,
  },
]
```

Desired result is:

```js
const overwrittenArr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    code: '1',
    bool: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    code: '2',
    bool: true,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    code: '3'
  },
]
```

`secondArr` should overwrite the `firstArr` by the `code` value, if it's exact the same value as in the `firstArr`, then it should be replaced with the object from the `secondArr`. I've tried to do that with `filter`, but had no success.

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `forEach` in order to mutate the first array like this:

```js
const firstArr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    code: '1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    code: '2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    code: '3'
  },
]

const secondArr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    code: '1',
    bool: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    code: '2',
    bool: true,
  },
]

secondArr.forEach(x => Object.assign(firstArr.find(y => y.id === x.id) || {}, x))

console.log(firstArr)
```

Comment: That's interesting way to use `Object.assign`, so it is the optimal way on achieving this?

Comment: I guess it is, if you don't mind overriding potential conflicting properties between the two objects

Answer (score 1):

You could assign the second array to the first.

```js
const
    firstArr = [{ id: 1, code: '1' }, { id: 2, code: '2' }, { id: 3, code: '3' }],
    secondArr = [{ id: 1, code: '1', bool: true }, { id: 2, code: '2', bool: true }];

Object.assign(firstArr, secondArr);

console.log(firstArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Dupe, dupe dupe. Including your answers too

Comment: Works because the items are sorted, the secondArr is shorter, there are no missing ids, and same object properties except `bool`

Answer (score 1):

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to the rescue!

```js
const firstArr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    code: '1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    code: '2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    code: '3'
  },
];

const secondArr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    code: '1',
    bool: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    code: '2',
    bool: true,
  },
];

const overwrittenArr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    code: '1',
    bool: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    code: '2',
    bool: true,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    code: '3'
  },
];

let result = Object.assign(firstArr, secondArr);

alert(JSON.stringify(result) === JSON.stringify(overwrittenArr));
```